# Cpanm failed to install modules

Tags: perl, cpan

I'd like to install Google::Chart module for perl, on ubuntu 12.10. If I try to install the module with the following command

```
cpanm Google::Chart
```

Error message:

```
--> Working on Google::Chart                                                                                                                                            
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DM/DMAKI/Google-Chart-0.05014.tar.gz ... OK                                                                                   
Configuring Google-Chart-0.05014 ... OK                                                                                                                                 
Building and testing Google-Chart-0.05014 ... FAIL                                                                                                                      
! Installing Google::Chart failed. See /root/.cpanm/work/1380032137.15804/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

Log file:

```
#   Failed test 'use Google::Chart;'
#   at /root/.cpanm/work/1380031926.15351/Google-Chart-0.05014/inc/Test/UseAllModules.pm line 69.
#     Tried to use 'Google::Chart'.
#     Error:  Attempt to reload Google/Chart/Color.pm aborted.
# Compilation failed in require at lib/Google/Chart.pm line 9.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at lib/Google/Chart.pm line 9.
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 350) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 350) line 2.

#   Failed test 'use Google::Chart::Marker;'
#   at /root/.cpanm/work/1380031926.15351/Google-Chart-0.05014/inc/Test/UseAllModules.pm line 69.
#     Tried to use 'Google::Chart::Marker'.
#     Error:  Attempt to reload Google/Chart/Color.pm aborted.
# Compilation failed in require at lib/Google/Chart/Marker.pm line 68.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at lib/Google/Chart/Marker.pm line 68.
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 378) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 378) line 2.
Bailout called.  Further testing stopped:  failed: Google::Chart::Color,Google::Chart,Google::Chart::Marker
FAILED--Further testing stopped: failed: Google::Chart::Color,Google::Chart,Google::Chart::Marker
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
-> FAIL Installing Google::Chart failed. See /root/.cpanm/work/1380031926.15351/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

Comment: Is there any other way to install this module?

Comment: Have you tried the plain, old fashion [cpan](http://perldoc.perl.org/cpan.html) command? Do you get the same errors? What about downloading the ZIP from the [CPAN archive](http://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/D/DM/DMAKI/Google-Chart-0.05014.tar.gz) and running through everything [manually](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html)? Let us know what happens with these steps.

Comment: Probably it's the bug reported in https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=86276 . There's a patch attached.

Comment: Yes, I have the same error if I use cpan command, too. I've downloaded the zip, and tried to install manually, I got this error:
Result: FAIL
Failed 8/12 test programs. 0/10 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255

Comment: When everything fails.... go for the copy/paste way. Go CPAN. Copy the stuff inside your perl's lib and run the script with perl -I "directory where you saved the module" script.pl (or better, add the directory in your bashrc)

Comment: I've successfully installed the module manually. :) Thanks guys! :)

Comment: Why do you install under the root account? You are not supposed to do that. Look at [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
cd /root/.cpanm/work/1380031926.15351/Google-Chart-0.05014/ (or wherever it's been unwrapped)
perl Makefile.PL
make && make install
```